# Deploying an Angular Universal app: Do I need the `server` directory?

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-ssr

I have an Angular 16 app that I built using Angular Universal to pre-render the pages for SEO purposes.

I run `ng run project-name:prerender` and it generates the following structure

```
├─ dist
│  ├─ project-name
│  │  ├─ browser
│  │  ├─ server
```

I can run the `dist/project-name/browser` locally and everything works as expected.

So my question is: **do I need to do anything with the `dist/project-name/server` directory?**

I understand it's there for server-side rendering, but this is a fairly simple application (just a dev/design portfolio for myself) and I have no need for anything to happen server side that I know of.

Comment: It says https://angular.io/guide/prerendering there *To prerender a static page make sure to add Server-Side Rendering (SSR) capabilities to your application.*

Comment: Yes I realize that, but my question is: do I need to do anything with the `/server` directory, or can I just disregard that?

Comment: Following. But it seems to work as expected with only the `browser` folder. I don't know why nguniversal generates a `server` folder though

Comment: Correct.  I've looked through their docs and there doesn't seem to be a way to only generate one or the other.  You can only get both, and then I guess you just whichever ones you need.  I wish I could disable generating the `server` folder though as it takes a bit longer to build and generates some errors about certain `window.*` methods not existing